# JLabel not Truncating Within JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, grid-layout

If I put a `JLabel` inside of a `JPanel` with no rigid boundaries, it does not truncate the text when the `JPanel` is sized to be smaller than the text. Why does this happen? Shouldn't the `JPanel` realize that there isn't enough room & truncate the text accordingly, regardless of its layout?

As an example, I created a `JFrame` with a `GridLayout` with two rows & one column. In that, I placed a `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout` on top, & a `JPanel` with a `BoxLayout`on the bottom. Each `JPanel` contains a `JLabel`.

In short: Why doesn't the `JLabel` on the top truncate its text?

Images to demonstrate what I mean:
[image]
[image]

As well, this is the SSCCE to demonstrate the effect:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TruncationTest1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Truncation Test");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //Default layout, aka FlowLayout
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Try resizing the frame: This will not be truncated for some reason.");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("However, this JLabel, on the other hand, will become truncated.");
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        f.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(panel);
            panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            panel.add(label);
        f.add(label2);
            label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details of proper thread handling in Swing.  Particularly the part about Initial Threads. 2) Call `f.pack();` just before `f.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FlowLayout` does not resize components inside it. It shows the components with preferred size.

You need to use different layout in place of `FlowLayout` for proper resizing. For instance you could use `BorderLayout` with the label at `LINE_START` or `WEST`.

Comment: *"..with the label at `LINE_START` or `WEST`."*  I prefer `LINE_START` since it is locale sensitive.